# Excel, OFFSET/INDEX, and Match from List

Tags: excel

Edited for sample:

I am attempting to fill in the Squads cell (G3) with "MP" from cell J1. I am doing this by checking if this squad has requested training, notated by a "YES" on their sheet. If there is a "YES" it fills in J1 with a number 1. I want to find the offset of a match to what will be a list of numbers with divisions (1 = MP, 2 = X, etc).

This is the equation I have so far tried varitions on in G2 to pull from the list.
=IF(J1=(MATCH(J1, K1)), OFFSET(MATCH(J1, K1),0,1), "")

I have attempted to use INDEX and MATCH as well. Either I get #VALUE, #N/A, or Excel tells me the equations is wrong depending on my variation. I have linked two pictures. The matching equation is giving me an error so I cannot save the IF statment as above.

[Find equation for J1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP7Co.jpg)
[Matching equation for G2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6d9k.jpg)

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53284987/edit) to add sample data and expected out come?

Answer (score 0):

[Final Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWPgL.jpg)
So update. I was able to do a little more research and fiddle with the code. My final code of was =IF(MATCH(J8, K1:K5), INDEX(J1:K5, MATCH(J8, K1:K5), 1), ""). This made the code look for through the indexed array and move the offset division next to the number. The find equation is still working as it should.